# Having trouble getting root.after() to work

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's some back ground to the problem: I'm currently trying to have a simple tkinter gui on a raspberry pi display the sensor readings from a thermometer/humidity sensor. However, before I get to that, I needed to check if I could get tkinter to update itself with new values. I've included the code I'm using. Right now, I'm trying to get the temperature in Celsius to increment up by 1 about every second by using root.after to call change(), which updates a certain label in the gui, while the code is in root.mainloop(). However, I'm encountering an error every time I try it, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

My code:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

    class Example(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")   

            self.parent = parent

            self.initUI()


        def initUI(self):

            self.parent.title("Interface")
            self.style = ttk.Style()
            self.style.theme_use("alt")

            self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

            self.tempLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Temperature", fg="black", bg="white")
            self.tempLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

            self.tempC = tk.Label(self, text="4654645˚ Celsius", fg="black", bg="white")
            self.tempC.grid(row=1, column=0)

            self.tempF = tk.Label(self, text="0˚ Fahrenheit", fg="black", bg="white")
            self.tempF.grid(row=2, column=0)

            self.rhLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Relative Humidity", fg="black", bg ="white")
            self.rhLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

            self.rh = tk.Label(self, text=" 53.37%", fg="black", bg="white")
            self.rh.grid(row=1, column=1)

        def change (self, variable, state):
            variable + 1
            newText = str(variable)

            if state ==1:
                newText += "%"
                self.rh.config(text=newText, width =20)
                self.rh.update_idletasks()

            elif state ==2:
                newText += "˚ Celsius"
                self.tempC.config(text=newText, width =20)
                self.tempC.update_idletasks()

            elif state ==3:
                newText += "˚ Fahrenheit"
                self.tempF.config(text=newText, width =20)
                self.tempF.update_idletasks()

            self.after(1000, self.change)

def main():
    var =0

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x250+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    app.change(var, 2)
    root.mainloop() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the error I get: (This error is fixed)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/tkinter_test.py", line 108, in <module>
main()
File "/home/pi/tkinter_test.py", line 102, in main
app.change(var, 2)
File "/home/pi/tkinter_test.py", line 92, in change
tk.Frame.after(1000, self.change)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 486, in after
self.tk.call('after', ms)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to python, so the issue in the code is probably stupid.

Edit:

Per Kevin's suggestion below, I changed tk.Frame.after(1000, self.change) to self.after(1000, self.change). However, I am now getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1426, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 490, in callit
func(*args)
TypeError: change() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

It seems to not be liking me calling self.change without any arguments when I use it in after(). However, looking online I never see arguments given to the module in after(), and when I do add them, I get a recursion error.

Comment: I don't think you can call `after` without supplying a widget instance. You can do `root.after` in `main` or `self.after` in `change`, but you can't just do `tk.Frame.after`. (I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer because I think after this you're going to run into a number of other issues before your code is working perfectly, and I haven't got time to solve them all)

Comment: Yeah, using self.root got the gui appearing (but not updating), and another error to appear. Thanks for the fix. I'll try to get past the new error, but if I fail, I'll add it to my post above.

Comment: Read the error message: it's telling you exactly what's wrong. You designed `change` to be called with arguments, but you aren't passing those arguments in when you call `after`.

Comment: Like I said above, all the examples online of after I've seen never put any arguments in. If I ignore those and do put arguments in, I get a recursion error.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use root.update() instead of root.after()? for me it works alot better like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
b = Frame(root)
root.update()
```

in this example i use root.update instead of root.mainloop(), but thay can be combined and the cool part of root.update() is that it does exactly what it says

Comment: i was just trying to help bryan, i cant see whats wrong with that

Comment: Yeah, i saw online that you could put root,update and root.update_idletasks in a while loop and it would serve roughly the same purpose as root.mainloop. If I can't get it working with mainloop I'll try that, but since root.mainloop is what you should use with tkinter Id like to get it working this way.